# Android WebView for long images

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm using WebView as an image viewer in my android application.
The image size is 750X3500 and I need to view the whole image, i.e. I want the maximum zoom out in order the image fit the screen.
It seems to me like impossible mission so far :(

Here is my WebView initialization code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And here is a sample image:

http://linkpeek.com/m/vault/c/8/3/c835da21e9d3bd65359d024d0feff30f4eb77cacccf6e477bc9fbb52848984cf.png

Any idea guys?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a `WebView`? There are plenty of zooming `ImageView` implementations floating around.

Comment: No one that implement "paging"/"level of details", i.e. change the resolution according to the zooming level. When you in the maximum zoom out you need low resolution, while you're in the maximum zoom in you need the full resolution. WebView handles this in the right way. Try to load the image I gave above to an ImageView and you'll see what I talking about...

Comment: If you use an HTML page to load the image, then you can use `"viewport"` HTML meta to try to control how it displays.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks. Thats solved my problem. You can post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an HTML page to load the image, then you can use ["viewport" HTML meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to control how it displays and zooms.